# Moment toDate with timezone does not give the correct time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

somehow i tried to get the timezone of America/New_York (my locale time is -1 hour from EST). But im always getting the same time when i use

```
moment(new Date()).tz("America\New_York").toDate()
```

Am i using the wrong method or what happened? Can someone help me out please?

here is a link to jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lgr3qdjf/

Answer (score 1):

per [this issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/644), moment `toDate` always returns the date with the system time zone, because a javascript Date object is always in the local timezone.

You can use `format` or `toString`, like below, to get the date in the desired timezone:

```
var estTime = moment(new Date()).tz("America/New_York").format();
```

Here's a runnable snippet to fully demonstrate:

```js
moment.tz.add([
    'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);

var estTime = moment(new Date()).tz("America/New_York").format();
console.log('StackOverflow Time:', new Date);
console.log('Eastern Time:', estTime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are not in the time zone you suspect you are (or at least your network is not)?

To test functionality, make sure you are using known values for each test. Below is an update to your example and a link to test further:

```
moment.tz.add([
  'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);

let utc_time = moment().utc().format();
let estTime = moment(utc_time).tz("America/New_York").format();

console.log(utc_time);
console.log(estTime)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/8aqpbo2h/4/